# Which one is correct? "I am glad to be taught by you" or "I am glad to have been taught by you"?

Tags: present-perfect, present-continuous

I want to tell my teacher that I am glad to have her as my teacher. Can I say "I am glad to be taught by you" or "I am glad to have been taught by you"?

Answer (score 1):

The form "I am glad..." would apply if she is still teaching you.
The form "I am glad to have been..." would apply if she is no longer teaching you.

It might be more idiomatic to say
"I am glad [ to have you / to have had you ] as my teacher."